# Regex with complex pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have a question, when matching the following

```
Functiona(Functionb(a, b, c)) + Functionc(Functionb(d, e))
```

where I only want to extract `Functiona(...), Functionb(...), Functionc(...)`

I have tried `Function[a-z]\(\w+\)*`

but the result is not as expected. Would anyone kindly correct the pattern? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to account for the parentheses (which are not word characters), and the commas and spaces (same)

Comment: I think i understand what means by @CertainPerformance... look like a bunch of if else might not able to skip anyway...

Comment: Regex isn't designed to deal with nested expressions like this. What you are looking for is a Recursive Descent Parser [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)

Comment: @BradleySmith Well, similarity is quite near, but without the begin end {} body concern... I'm not creating whole new language... but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex based on the [**balancing groups** construct](https://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html):

```
(?=(?<res>\bFunction[A-Za-z]\((?:[^()]*|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*(?(o)(?!))\)))
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3D%28%3F%3Cres%3E%5CbFunction%5BA-Za-z%5D%5C%28%28%3F%3A%5B%5E%28%29%5D*%7C%28%3F%3Co%3E%29%5C%28%7C%28%3F%3C-o%3E%29%5C%29%29*%28%3F%28o%29%28%3F!%29%29%5C%29%29%29&i=Functiona%28Functionb%28a%2C%20b%2C%20c%29%29%20%2B%20Functionc%28Functionb%28d%2C%20e%29%29)

The outer lookahead is used to enable overlapped matches, as it makes the regex engine test each location inside the string. Once the lookahead pattern is matched, it is pushed onto Group `res` and these values are accessible from the `matchObj.Groups["res"].Value`.

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `Function` - a literal word
- `[A-Za-z]` - an ASCII letter
- `\(` - a `(`
- `(?:[^()]*|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*` - zero or more occurrences of 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`, `(` (that are pushed on to the Group `o` stack), `)` (that are popped from the `o` group stack)
- `(?(o)(?!))` - a conditional check to fail the match if Group `o` is not empty
- `\)` - a outer `)`.

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/wFTwfr):

```
var s = "Functiona(Functionb(a, b, c)) + Functionc(Functionb(d, e))";
    var pattern = @"(?=(?<res>\bFunction[A-Za-z]\((?:[^()]*|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*(?(o)(?!))\)))";
    var result = Regex.Matches(s, pattern)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Groups["res"].Value)
        .ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", result));
```

Output:

```
Functiona(Functionb(a, b, c))
Functionb(a, b, c)
Functionc(Functionb(d, e))
Functionb(d, e)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your string would be successfully matched by the following two regular expressions:

Function[a-z]([a-zA-Z(,\s+(]*)+

Function[a-z]([a-z,\s]*)

For whatever reason, when I wrap these in an OR it doesn't identify both sets:

(Function[a-z]([a-zA-Z(,\s+(]*)+|Function[a-z]([a-z,\s]*))

Depending on where/how you are evaluating the string, you could simply make two passes, one with each pattern, and take the identified matches. It isn't a great solution but it does identify all possible matches.

Comment: actually I do have try that before, but that is not quite what I expected, coz the case might much more complex then this. But Wiktor Stribiżew does give the solution that I have been expected. Thanks anyway.